# Deprecation warning for save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the strange warning I am getting all over my rails server logs

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The behavior of `changed_attributes` inside of after callbacks will be changing in the next version of Rails. The new return value will reflect the behavior of calling the method after `save` returned (e.g. the opposite of what it returns now). To maintain the current behavior, use `saved_changes.transform_values(&:first)` instead.

Here is the code that is causing it

```
def create_account
  user = User.new(
    first_name: @user_details['first_name'],
    last_name: @user_details['last_name'],
    email: @user_details['email'],
    timezone: @user_details['timezone'],
    locale: @user_details['locale'],
    :remote_avatar_url => @user_details['picture']['data']['url'].to_s
  )
  if user.save ## this is the line that seems to be in logs
    render json: {
      auth_token: user.auth_token,
      status: 200,
      show_categories_screen: true
    }
  else
    render json: { errors: user.errors.messages, status: 500 }
  end
end
```

Rails version is 5.1.2

Comment: Are there any callbacks in the User model?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: I want to know what causes this depreciation warning

Comment: @gates: your use of abovementioned methods causes the warning. Or maybe it's just an obligatory warning for everyone.

Comment: No call backs @hedgesky

Comment: How do I prevent it @SergioTulentsev, can you help me out please

Comment: @gates: sure. Review all of your code (in models). If you use `changed_attributes` anywhere, apply the workaround to keep the current behaviour. If you don't use that method, ignore the warning.

Comment: @gates, Sergio is correct.  You may also need to consider any gems that may be extending your models (Devise for example).  If a gem is causing the warning, you may want to investigate the gem's homepage to ensure the issue is being addresses.  In the end, this only becomes a problem if and when you upgrade to a later (future) version of Rails.